# function is not returning any value

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I need to write a recursive function that should return the largest number in a given array,
I'm using the method .splice() to remove the smaller numbers. When I have just one element in my array I will return that element witch would be the biggest number in the array

the logic seems working but is not returning anything, any ideas?

```
function findMax(arr){
    // This function returns the largest number in a given array
     if (arr.length === 1){
        const bigNum = arr.pop();
        return bigNum
    }
    else if (arr[0] > arr[1]){
        arr.splice(1,1)
        findMax(arr)
    }
    else{
        arr.splice(0,1)
        findMax(arr)    
        }

}

y = findMax([1,6,8,2,10,5]);

y
undefined
```

Comment: One observation, you need to add `return` before each recursive call, example: `return findMax(arr);`

Comment: Why are you using `splice` at all? If all you want to do is find the maximum, you don't need to modify the array.

Comment: Additionally it isn't a good idea to use a recursion where it isn't necessary. I suggest using `.reduce()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the results of the recursion:

```js
function findMax(arr){
    // This function returns the largest number in a given array
     if (arr.length === 1){
        const bigNum = arr.pop();
        return bigNum
    }
    else if (arr[0] > arr[1]){
        arr.splice(1,1)
        return findMax(arr)
    }
    else{
        arr.splice(0,1)
        return findMax(arr)    
        }

}

y = findMax([1,6,8,2,10,5]);
console.log(y)
```

Another option if you're looking for something a little simpler is to compare with the result of the recursion directly and return the largest:

```js
function findMax(arr){
    // This function returns the largest number in a given array
    if (arr.length <=1) return arr[0]
    
    let [head, ...rest] = arr

    let rec = findMax(rest)
    return head > rec ? head : rec
    // or just:
    // return Math.max(head, findMax(rest))

}

y = findMax([10, 9, 14, 3, 1, -2]);
console.log(y)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark and Shidersz

I know my solution is not the most beautiful and I just playing around trying to learn recursion, I was just concern about the return witch was driving me crazy LOL

thanks a lot guys